# Merging two files using jq

Tags: json, jq

I've got two files.

First:

```
[
  { "person1": [] },
  { "person2": [] }
]
```

Second:

```
[
  {
    "person2": { "attribute1": "wer", "attribute2": "sdf" }
  },
  {
    "person2": { "attribute1": "ert", "attribute2": "dfg" }
  },
  {
    "person2": { "attribute1": "rty", "attribute2": "fgh" }
  },
  {
    "person3": { "attribute1": "tyu", "attribute2": "ghj" }
  },
  {
    "person1": { "attribute1": "yui", "attribute2": "hjk" }
  }
]
```

I try to merge them, using `jq`. For each person from the first file (in the second file migth be more persons, which should be ignored) create list of it's attributes. So an output should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "person1":
      [
        { "attribute1": "yui", "attribute2": "hjk" }
      ]
  },
  {
    "person2":
      [
        { "attribute1": "wer", "attribute2": "sdf" },
        { "attribute1": "ert", "attribute2": "dfg" },
        { "attribute1": "rty", "attribute2": "fgh" }
      ]
  }
]
```

I tried different options, but I can't achieve expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq 'reduce (input[]|to_entries[]) as $e (add;
  if has($e.key) then .[$e.key] += [$e.value] else . end
) | [keys_unsorted[] as $k|{($k): .[$k]}]' file1 file2
```

<sub>[online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/z1S9TcgWwv)</sub>

Comment: I came up with something similar: `reduce (inputs[]|to_entries[]) as {key:$k,value:$v} (INDEX(keys[0]); if has($k) then .[$k][$k] += [$v] else . end) | [.[]]`

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is focused on efficiency, and also suggests an alternative format for the output:

#### jq program (merge.jq)

```
add as $dict
# aggregation:
| (reduce input[] as $record ({};
   ($record|keys_unsorted[0]) as $person
   | if $dict[$person] then .[$person] += [$record[$person]] else . end )) as $answer
# re-arrangement
| reduce ($dict|keys_unsorted[]) as $person ([]; . + [ {($person): $answer[$person] } ] )
```

### Invocation

```
jq -f merge.jq first.json second.json
```

Comment: You get an alternative format if you drop the “rearrangement”.

Comment: Oh, okay. And excuse my ignorance but how do we know if our program is efficient or not? I always try running it with huge arbitrary inputs, but is there an easier way?

Comment: @oguzismail - Big topic. Mainly I have in mind both theoretical space-time efficiencies (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency) and practical jq-specific considerations.